# Jquery .html method does not seem to work

Tags: javascript, jquery, three.js, editor, sweetalert

[The editor project](https://jseditortest.glitch.me) I am making should allow me to Import a cdn library and use it to write code . So to show my problem , enter https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r128/three.min.js in the import cdn input and click import . Then enter this in the code section :

```
const scene = new THREE.Scene();
const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );

const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry();
const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x00ff00 } );
const cube = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
scene.add( cube );

camera.position.z = 5;

const animate = function () {
    requestAnimationFrame( animate );
    cube.rotation.x += 0.01;
    cube.rotation.y += 0.01;
    renderer.render( scene, camera );
};

animate();
```

Click the run button at the top . You should get a tiny three js window at the bottom. My first question is , why is the text undefined coming above the render ? And two , if you change the code in the input to :

```
const scene = new THREE.Scene();
const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );

const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry();
const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x00ff00 } );
const cube = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
scene.add( cube );

camera.position.z = 5;

const animate = function () {
    requestAnimationFrame( animate );
    cube.rotation.x += 0.01;
    cube.rotation.y += 0.01;
    renderer.render( scene, camera );
};

animate();
```

It adds another render to the div . Why ? especially when I have used the .html method to replace the contents of the div . My complete code is visible [here](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/jseditortest)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By inspecting the Javascript console, it's clear that the renderer is not added to #body2 but rather to the document.body.

This line:

```
document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
```

appends the renderer to the body element.

The undefined is because of `String( eval( $("#editor #editor-textarea").val() ));`

The text content in eval must return something.
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_eval.asp

In this case, the return value of `$("#editor #editor-textarea").val()` is undefined. Hence `eval(undefined)` is `undefined` and `String(undefined)` is `"undefined"`

Comment: Thanks a ton ! But if I cannot use `document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
` then what do I use? And how do I remove the undefined text?

Comment: You can set the content as iframe src and change it on each submit.
This also isolates the code from the parent document so it won't affect the page.

Made a gist here: https://gist.github.com/chaitanya-deep/f31848f2270d682611ef4577b4c6800b

Comment: Nice  . Thanks , but I have two question . In the gist , iframe wasn't even used . It just seems to be set to ` document.getElementById("body2");` . And what is const content ? Is it the iframe body ? If it is , then why are the script tags going in there?

Comment: "body2" is the ID of the iframe.
File index.html line 40.

Yes. content is the body of iframe. scriptTags is the list of all the imports the user adds. Line 16. When the user adds a library, it's added to the head as a script tag so it's available to use in the code written by the user

Comment: Ah ,thanks a lot . Marking it correct.